# Asymptotic property of integral involving Bessel function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, asymptotics

Consider the following integral
$$
I(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{J_{\frac{n-2}{2}}}(sr)r^{A+1}(e^{-r^{2\alpha}}-1)dr,
$$
where $J_{\frac{n-2}{2}}$ is the Bessel function of order ${\frac{n-2}{2}}$, $s, A, \alpha>0$. I want to know the asymptotic property of $I(s)$ when $s\to+\infty$. Especially, I expect that we have $I(s)=o(s^{-\frac{n+2}{2}-A})$.

I think the way to estimate such kinds of integrals is stationary phase. Can someone show me how to deal with it? Thanks very much

Comment: When does your integral converge?  For example, for $n=1$, $A = 1/2$, and $s = 1$ the integrand is proportional to $r \cos r (e^{-r^{2\alpha}}-1) \approx -r \cos r$, and the integral of this diverges.

Comment: I think one can put the term $e^{-\epsilon|r|}$ in the integral and then let $\epsilon\to 0$